# Coalesce datetime values and convert to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following in my query:

```
( case
  when clientplans.start_date='1899-12-30 00:00:00.000' then ''
  else CONVERT(varchar,clientplans.START_DATE,112)
  end
) as POLICY_EFF_DATE,
```

I am getting some NULLs which I need to COALESCE to empty strings.

I tried the following, among other variations, without success:

```
( case
  when clientplans.start_date='1899-12-30 00:00:00.000' then ''
  else COALESCE( CONVERT(varchar,clientplans.START_DATE,112) , '' )
  end
) as POLICY_EFF_DATE,
```

How can I get rid of the NULLs?

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ISNULL on date column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240444/using-isnull-on-date-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
select policy_eff_date = case coalesce(cp.start_date,'')
                           when ''                        then ''
                           when '1899-12-30 00:00:00.000' then ''
                           else convert(varchar , cp.start_date , 112 )
                         end ,
       policy_exp_date = case sign( datediff(day,getdate(),coalesce(cp.end_date,'')) )
                           when -1 then ''
                           else         convert(varchar,cp.end_date,112)
                         end ,
       ...
from clientplans cp
...
```

Since `''` is treated at the epoch of the SQL Server calendar (its zero-point, `1 January 1900 00:00:00.000`), the net result is that

- A `null` datetime values are treated as if it were the epoch, `1 January 1900 00:00:00.00'
- The epoch datetime value is converted to an empty string
- The datetime value `30 Dec 1899 00:00:00.000` is likewise converted to an empty string
- All other datetime values are converted to a string in ISO 8601 short form (`YYYYMMDD`) using the 112 conversion format

With your expiration date, `null` expiration dates and expiration dates prior to the current date are represented as an empty string; anything else is converte to ISO 8601 short form (`YYYYMMDD`).

Comment: This was the perfect solution.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can also reverse the logic:

```
(case when clientplans.start_date > '1899-12-30 00:00:00.000' 
      then CONVERT(varchar(255), clientplans.START_DATE, 112)
      else ''
 end) as POLICY_EFF_DATE,
```

Note:  when using `varchar()` in SQL Server, you should always include a length.  The default length varies by context, and depending on it can lead to unexpected -- and very hard to find -- errors.

EDIT:

For the end date, it is the same idea:

(case when clientplans.END_DATE >= cast(getdate() as date)
         then convert (varchar(255), clientplans.END_DATE, 112)
    end) as POLICY_EXP_DATE

Comment: That works fine for the start date but im using the same logic for the expiration date.  I need to replace null with ''  (case when clientplans.END_DATE < cast(getdate() as date) then '' else convert (varchar(255),clientplans.END_DATE,112)end) as POLICY_EXP_DATE,