# Using ISNULL or COALESCE on date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I’ve got a date column where some rows have got NULL values. I would like to use ISNULL or something like that to substitute those values with something like ‘N/A’, however, when I try to use ISNULL, I get an error due to two different data types. If I try to convert my Date column to VARCHAR in order to be able to use ISNULL, then the way my column displays dates gets distorted. Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
ISNULL(DateSent, 'N/A')
```

Comment: share your table structure

Comment: This is a 'presentation layer' issue. Where do you want to see N/A? in a report?

Comment: Dont use 'N/A' for null values and keep the DateTime (or whatever your date-type currently is). If you must - create a view that has a stringified date or 'N/A'

Comment: When you convert date to varchar you can choose the style.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend `COALESCE()`, because it is standard.  However, your problem is that the first column is a date/time and that is not compatible with a string.

So, you need to convert the value.  You can use the default format:

```
COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), DateSent), 'N/A')
```

Or you can add a conversion argument:

```
COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), DateSent, 120), 'N/A')
```

Or you can use `FORMAT()` for more flexibility.

Comment: COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), DateSent, 120), 'N/A') - this worked exactly how I needed it to work! Thanks

Comment: This question and answer deserve a thousand more up-votes. This is EXACTLY what I've been searching for.. Bravo!

Comment: SQL Server ISNULL() and COALESCE() are not identical. https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/coalesce-vs-isnull#:~:text=One%20apparent%20advantage%20that%20COALESCE%20has%20over%20ISNULL,the%20ISO%2FANSI%20SQL%20standards%29%2C%20whereas%20ISNULL%20is%20T-SQL%E2%80%93specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
Select ISNULL(Cast(DateSent as Varchar(20)), 'N/A')
```

Below is one example:

```
declare @DateSent date = getdate()
Select ISNULL(Cast(@DateSent as Varchar(20)), 'N/A')
```

For null values as below.

```
declare @DateSent1 date = NULL
Select ISNULL(Cast(@DateSent1 as Varchar(20)), 'N/A')
```